# Divs heights 100% in a container div without static height

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, positioning

I had a problem today. I had 3 divs with variable heights, I never knew which one of them will be the highest. I had to position them side by side and always set the height of all 3 of them to be the same. All 3 divs are positioned in a wrapper div, but this one can't have static height, it needs to adjust itself to the highest child.

My solusion include some simple javascript:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqha2/)

I hope some of you might find it usefull at some point...

Comment: I Took out the javascript and the `#wrap` div gets the hight of the tallest `<div>` automatically [http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/qqha2/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/qqha2/4/), as you required. Is this a browser specific problem?

Comment: I want all divs inside the wrapper the same height. It is described in the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this example: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/Dyy4M/

Answer (score 0):

After leaving my comment i noticed you had a clear div:

`<div class="clear" />`

Im against using markup to solve problems. This can be done with adding two CSS lines:

```
#wrap
{
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid red;
    float:left; /* NEW LINE */
    width:100%; /* NEW LINE */  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/qqha2/5/

Answer (score -1):

i think it was just easier to create a table for that particular case... with 1 row and 3 cells... not 100% correctly semantically, but i think better than custom javascript for such thing...

Comment: NO NO NO! Dont ever use tables for layout, sloppy and lazy. @Ahsan Rathod method proves it can be done using CSS

Comment: i agree with your comment :) however i think that using javascript for this is even worse. to sum up: do not use neither of this methods.

Comment: and just by the way. do not give minus just because someone mentions about table. Who told you that it will be used for the layout :) ? there are many scenarios in which you just want to display 3 blocks of text and you do not know which is bigger. in such case, table is not a sin. yes, you can do it probably on divs as you mentioned, but what is the purpose? table is not always terrible. think about it :)